# Xpath not found

Tags: xpath, robotframework

When executing the test case, this error is shown:

Button with locator 'xpath=//*[@id="stBanner"]/div[2]/a[2]' not found.

The element doesnt't have an id, and I have to use Xpath, but it can't be found.

This is the code when I inspect the element:

```
<div class="stRight">
   <span id="mobileSearchIcon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
       <!-- Logged in --><!-- Logged out -->
           <a class="user-sts-link" href=" uri=nm:oid:Z6_72A2IA80O0US40QOM4JF0F30O3">REGISTER</a>
           <a class="user-sts-link" href="?uri=nm:oid:Z6_72A2IA80O0CSB0Q4ODDFDQ0081">LOGIN</a>
</div>
```

This is the xpath:

```
//*[@id="stBanner"]/div[2]/a[2]
```

This is the testcase:

```
SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser    @{tst3Url}[0]    firefox
SeleniumLibrary.Click Button    xpath=//*[@id="stBanner"]/div[2]/a[2]
```

Comment: Add a bigger chunk of the HTML - not just the `a` element, but also the `div` surrounding it, and the element above the `div`.

Comment: What happens when you try this xpath in a browser - is the element found?

Comment: @Todor already updated the HTML code. When I try this Xpath in a broswer the element is found.

Comment: In the sample you've provided, `//div/a[2]` does match the element with the "LOGIN" test; so if you add the parent HTML element in the question, we'll see where it fails.

Comment: I don't understand what you ask. How can I add the parent HTML element? I only inspect the button login and copy the XPath.

Comment: Your xpath says "find the 2nd `a` element, that is a child of the 2nd `div`, which is a child of an element with that id". You've put in the question just just the `a` and the `div`, but not the element above the `div`.

Comment: Nevermind, I found your issue.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, if you need I add the element above. Sorry for the silly questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `Click Button` keyword - it is strictly for html elements of the `<button>` type.

Instead, use `Click Element` - your target element is an `<a>`, and with `Click Elements` the browser will execute the click on it.